# Modal for hyperlink in Leaflet app

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, hyperlink, modal

I have a simple Leaflet app that maps some custom points (bars, restaurants, etc...).

[image]

Currently, when the user clicks on on of the marker icons, a popup appears that displays a hyperlink of the location's name (ex: Slim's bar). If the user clicks on the hyperlink name, it takes them to the website (ex: www.slimsraleigh.com). The problem is that, in doing so, it takes the user out of the app and to a completely new page. What I'd like to have happen is that the page still comes up, but inside of a modal that the use can X out of once they are finished and want to view another locations website; basically, they remain in the app. How would you suggest I do this? I see there is a Leaflet Modal that can be loaded via NPM (I am using Node JS, so that should be easy), but the logistics of linking the modal to a click event of the hyperlink is where I am stuck. Below is the code where .Name and .Link (2 properties of my geoJson data) are utilized to make the hyperlink in the popup. Can anyone suggest a way I can accomplish my goal if getting the hyperlink tied to the modal?

```
L.geoJson(dtr_points, {
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("<a href=" + feature.properties.Link + ">" + feature.properties.Name + "</a>");

     if(feature.properties.Type == "beer") {
        layer.setIcon(beer);
     };
     if(feature.properties.Type == "bar") {
        layer.setIcon(bar);
     };
     if(feature.properties.Type == "restaurant") {
        layer.setIcon(restaurant);
     };
     if(feature.properties.Type == "music") {
        layer.setIcon(music);
     };
     if(feature.properties.Type == "culture") {
        layer.setIcon(culture);
     };
     if(feature.properties.Type == "cafe") {
        layer.setIcon(cafe);
     };
     if(feature.properties.Type == "occult shop") {
        layer.setIcon(occult);
     };


  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's a bad idea. You don't want to display another website inside a popup, it'll be a poor user experience.

What you could do is [open the link in a new tab](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target).

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

Comment: I tried this several times without success. The website would popup, but not in a new tab. And it would always have an issue. I noticed that the url at the top would also say `http://www.<site name>.com/target='_blank'`. I tried multiple syntax iterations of the following, but nothing worked:  `layer.bindPopup("<a href=" + feature.properties.Link + " target='_blank'>" + feature.properties.Name + "</a>");` Not sure why this isn't working, because it should.

Comment: YOu better ask another question. Your issue, though, is that you're not escaping your " properly. Try making the string in a var first `var link_url = "<a href='" + feature.properties.Link + "' target='_blank'>" + feature.properties.Name + "</a>"` and then `console.log(link_url)` to check what you are using.

Comment: After retesting this solutions, I got it working. Again, there seemed to be some syntax issue related to the " "s. A separate window now pops up. However, I am not so sure about this solution for mobile devices. The app is designed to provide an easy to use guide of downtown hotspots for visitors to a convention. Using a modal may make more sense when the app is launched from a mobile device, whereas it would look clunky on a laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want some more markup to identify those links in leaflet popups:

```
layer.bindPopup('<a class="weblink" href='...
```

Then, if you are using jQuery, you can register clicks on those links with:

```
$('div.leaflet-popup a.weblink').on('click', function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var html = '<iframe src="' + href + '"></iframe>';
    e.preventDefault(); // so we don't open the link directly

    // then use the leaflet-modal plugin you mentioned in the question
    map.fire('modal', {
        content: html, // HTML string 
    });
})
```